# json object push overwrite all item using last item in the loop?

Tags: javascript, json, each

```
var options = [];
$(b).each(function (a) {
    debugger;
    s += '<option value=\'' + b[a].Material + '\'>' + b[a].Material + '</option>'
    item = {};
    item["name"] = b[a].Material;
    item["value"] = b[a].Material;
    item["checked"] = false;
    options.push(item);
});
console.log(options);
```

Value of `s` is

```
<option value='MAB380-01'>MAB380-01</option>
<option value='MAB380-02'>MAB380-02</option>
```

In first iteration, `options` has `MAB380-01`.
But after second iteration, `options` has 2 of `MAB380-02`.

Firefox and Chrome give me correct result, but not IE.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. It's totally OK.  https://jsfiddle.net/f67my2n0

Comment: @MahbubMoon now that's weird, that's not what I get in IE 11.

Comment: callback of each takes two arguments first one is index and second is value. https://jsfiddle.net/krwb2914/. Modified from @Mahbub Moon. try that

Comment: can't reproduce on IE11

Comment: try to console log value inside each callback

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var options = [];
$(b).each(function (a) {
    debugger;
    s += '<option value=\'' + b[a].Material + '\'>' + b[a].Material + '</option>'
    var item = new Object();
    item.name = b[a].Material;
    item.value = b[a].Material;
    item.checked = false;
    options.push(item);
});
console.log(options);
```

These code work on Chrome, Firefox, and IE11.